# Возможно ли подписание ETH смарт контракта двумя контрагентами просто зная его адрес?

Tags: smart-contract, solidity

Возможно ли подписание ETH смарт контракта двумя контрагентами просто зная его адрес? Только имея MetaMask.

Возможно ли морозить средства первого контрагента до подписания вторым и возвращать их после истечения определенного времени? Если второй контрагент не подписал.

Спасибо за ликбез.